# Get subobject of object in hierarchy

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

```
  with sample_data as (select '26.03.2015 14:10' as adate, 4 as type, 40 as object, 111 as barcode from dual union all
                       select '26.03.2015 14:09' as adate, 1 as type, 55 as object, 222 as barcode from dual union all
                       select '26.03.2015 14:08' as adate, 2 as type, 33 as object, 777 as barcode from dual union all
                       select '26.03.2015 14:08' as adate, 2 as type, 34 as object, null as barcode from dual union all
                       select '26.03.2015 13:20' as adate, 3 as type, 41 as object, null as barcode from dual union all
                       select '26.03.2015 12:00' as adate, 1 as type, 56 as object, 444 as barcode from dual union all
                       select '26.03.2015 11:59' as adate, 2 as type, 37 as object, 555 as barcode from dual union all
                       select '26.03.2015 11:59' as adate, 2 as type, 48 as object, null as barcode from dual)
  select 
  adate, type, object, barcode
  from sample_data 
  where type in (1, 2);
```

type 1 is finished building, type 2 is part of assembly

i need next result

```
55 | 222 | 26.03.2015 14:08 | 33
55 | 222 | 26.03.2015 14:08 | 34
56 | 444 | 26.03.2015 11:59 | 37
56 | 444 | 26.03.2015 11:59 | 38
```

so we see what object **55** contain subobject **33**, **34** and two date = **26.03.2015 14:08** 
and object **56** contain subobject **37**, **38** and two date = **26.03.2015 11:59**

in begin i know two parameters - date and barcode  of finished building, for example on my data - date **26.03.2015 14:09** and barcode **222** or date **26.03.2015 12:00** and barcode **444**

Comment: What is the connection between object and subobjects? Is it due to the order by date?

Comment: all previous subobjects with type 2 before current object with type 1

Answer (score 0):

This query does the job. Subquery T1 connects "types 1" with "types 2". T2 enumerates them using function row_number().
Last query filters only rows with rn = 1.

```
with t1 as (
  select t.*, prior object pob, prior barcode pbc, 
      prior adate pad, level, sys_connect_by_path(object, '-') pth
    from sample_data t where level=2 
    connect by prior adate > adate and prior type = 1 and type = 2),
t2 as (select t1.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by object order by pad) rn from t1 )
select pob, pbc, adate, object from t2 where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
       POB        PBC ADATE               OBJECT
---------- ---------- ------------------- ----------
        55        222 2015-03-26 14:08:00         33
        55        222 2015-03-26 14:08:00         34
        56        444 2015-03-26 11:59:00         37
        56        444 2015-03-26 11:59:00         48
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define groups and then you can assign the items to the groups

```
with sample_data as (select '26.03.2015 14:10' as adate, 4 as type, 40 as object, 111 as barcode from dual union all
                     select '26.03.2015 14:09' as adate, 1 as type, 55 as object, 222 as barcode from dual union all
                     select '26.03.2015 14:08' as adate, 2 as type, 33 as object, 777 as barcode from dual union all
                     select '26.03.2015 14:08' as adate, 2 as type, 34 as object, null as barcode from dual union all
                     select '26.03.2015 13:20' as adate, 3 as type, 41 as object, null as barcode from dual union all
                     select '26.03.2015 12:00' as adate, 1 as type, 56 as object, 444 as barcode from dual union all
                     select '26.03.2015 11:59' as adate, 2 as type, 37 as object, 555 as barcode from dual union all
                     select '26.03.2015 11:59' as adate, 2 as type, 48 as object, null as barcode from dual),
     sd_groups as (select adate, lag(adate, 1) over (order by adate) adate_last, object, barcode from (
                     select * from sample_data where type = 1
                     union all select min(adate), null, null, null from sample_data))
select sg.object, sg.barcode, sd.adate, sd.object
from sample_data sd, sd_groups sg
where sd.type = 2 and sd.adate between sg.adate_last and sg.adate;
```